# How do I make a shoppingcart in asp.net when I have loaded some items in a gridview and want to add the selected one to my shoppingcart?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, shopping-cart

I have tried to make the selectbutton an templatefield and insert the selected item in a accesdatabase via a SQL insert commant but it didn't work.
I am sorry if this is bad english.
Regards
Pieter

Comment: Maybe if you showed your code someone could help?

Comment: can you send your command to set data to access database?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do this indirectly throught tha asp.net server side. If you dont know how to handle it, you should put server side button (from tool box) and after that double click on the button than you pass into the server side code to handle the click event. In this method you can do more powerful things include update the database via Ado.Net.